# Video quality too bad while playing (any) videos in Intel GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, graphics, video, intel-graphics

I have searched blogs and forums, installed several drivers, but can't find a solution that can provide equivalent video quality as that of Windows 7. Kindly help.

**Video quality** specially **color is too bad** while playing with any media player. Configuration details are:

1. **Ubuntu - 12.04**
2. **Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated**
3. The results of the following commands are

a)  `sudo lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
```

b) `find /dev -group video`

```
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/controlD64
/dev/agpgart
```

c)  `glxinfo | grep -i vendor`

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: ATI
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
```

d) `sudo lshw -C video`

```
*-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:fea00000-feafffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:efe8(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:feb00000-febfffff
```

I have spent days installing various drivers, and then un-installing but can't come up with a solution. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Dell desktop, running Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity 2D), with a Intel 82865G integrated video and it suffers the same thing.

That being said, I did install the drivers from Stefan Glasenhardt's PPA and the graphic quality of videos improved. Still not 100% but a lot better. Not sure if you had tried these or not; but they did make an improvement for me.

The PPA is: ppa:glasen/intel-driver and details for the PPA can be found at: https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver

Hope it helps. If you have tried it; sorry to waste your time.