# Should I install Intel Graphics Installer for Intel Mobile GM965/GL960

Tags: drivers, video, intel-graphics, 14.04

Colours are especially bad when viewing the same video file in Windows 7. Another user also mentioned [it before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177007/video-quality-too-bad-while-playing-any-videos-in-intel-gm965-gl960-integrated), so if anyone can update me on the issue, I'll be grateful.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

results of `lspci -v | less` are:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff64
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff64
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
        Memory at 92100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5110 [size=8]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff64
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at 92200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
```

P.S. I'm aware that Intel Graphics Installer is not yet available to 14.04, but when it does, I want to know if I should install it, or if it will make any difference on my overall video performance.

Answer (score 5):

The [Intel Graphics Installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/) enhances many features in several graphics cards and fixes many bugs apart from making the whole installation easier. That being said, it is always recommend to install it when the end user is using an Intel Graphics cards.

This will give you the latest Intel drivers with support for the latest Mesa drivers.

Comment: New version is out there https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.4
It just helped me install driver for graphic card mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine you'd get a performance increase on a chipset that old, but it probably won't hurt to try.  We can't say anything for certain until it actually gets released.

Comment: I have a really old system with intel video, and i get bad video, colors weird purples and greens. The intel drivers solve the problem.